# How to - auto submitting a javascript form

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter

i report a lot of my own work to twitter to take down through their https://support.twitter.com/forms/dmca

I am trying to find a way to make the process faster. i know the form is in javascript. i want to be able to prefill certain fields so that i dont have to (your full name, company, job title, email address etc). I did some research and some people say it can be done with python using urllib2. I also tried taking the html of their entire page and putting it on wamp to see if i can submit from there, but no luck.

I was hoping some one can point me in the right direction.

Update:
I found some info on proxy using python and it seems to be the way to go. Does anyone have any experience in this to point me in the right direction?

Comment: maybe chrome auto-fill could help? http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142893

Comment: thank you! but browser plugins are not an option unfortunately. I need it for other users to be able to use from my page.